# Why does Windows 11 Notepad Word Wrap even when the setting is off (and how to fix)?

Tags: windows, windows-11, notepad

Opening a file with very long lines in Windows 11 Notepad, I expect to be able to toggle word wrap as in previous editions of notepad. However, despite the word wrap setting being off, the lines are still wrapped. Is there a way to *actually* turn off word wrap for this file so I can see the whole lines one by one?

As you can see in this image, the whole line is not displayed on one line, but rather over several lines due to wrapping:

[image]

Clearly the Word Wrap setting is indeed turned off, however:

[image]

With the Word Wrap setting on, we get more wrapping, as you may expect:

[image]

The same file as viewed in Notepad++:
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your screenshots do not indicate whatever problem you think exists.

Comment: Nothing can be deduced from your picture.  No evidence of wrapping in the initial pics.  With wrapping on it seems to show wrapping as expected. My money is on no wrapping in initial views but you are assuming wrapping.  Write a long line of text at the top of the file, then narrow the window and see if it actually wraps. (E. G. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... Etc.

Comment: Apologies if I have used the incorrect terminology - the blue highlighted line with numbers from 1 to 1852 is all one line in the original file, and yet it is being displayed over several lines here. I can tell this because the 22s at the beginning of the displayed lines are not 22 but rather 1022, 1222, 1422, 1622 ,1822. The 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 etc are at the end of the "line" above. The blue highlight was generated by triple-clicking (i.e. select line). These are test cases from a programming question and so they follow a very specific format - a line of two numbers then two very long lines.

Comment: In contrast if I open the file in VSCode, I do see the original line structure, however it is truncated after a certain number of characters and replaced with ..., which isn't ideal. I have found an alternative which is to use Notepad++ which shows me the whole lines as intended, however it would be nice to know how to fix Notepad to do this (edited to show N++)